# Limiting activity via PHP

Tags: php, security, spam

I have a social network that allows users to post blogs, ask questions, and message. We have had a slight issue with spamming. For example, we had users sign up, and write about 6 blogs a minute trying to sell stuff.

I am looking for a quick way to limit these activities by the id of the user, let's say only allowing them to post 3 blogs a day.

I have the users stored in a `$auth` variable and through OOP bring them up by `$auth->id` for example to be more specific.

Looking for a fast,simple way to do this via php.

thanks in advance /*******EDIT************/

this is what I have so far, and I know for sure $too many is counting as it should, but for some reason my `if(statement` is not stopping the 4th blog from posting. [HERE](https://gist.github.com/298a8625be1c5e3f78f5) is the code

Comment: Perhaps a better idea would be to implement a CAPTCHA either on sign up or on posting blogs, that would certainly dent the amount of bot spamming

Comment: we have captchas but not for those sections. That would help,and will do, but these were manual users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) would be appropriate. However, if they're being entered manually, it will do little to stop them. Regardless, no reason you can't implement both methods.

I'm assuming you have a `created` field in your blogs table. Simply query the table for the number of blogs with today's date before allowing another to be posted. Not sure what database/API you're using. In MySQL, you could do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM blogs 
WHERE user_id = USERID 
AND DATE(created) = '2011-11-30'
```

Comment: +1 cause I wasn't game enough to add my CAPTCHA comment as a partial answer, re-CAPTCHA is a good one

Answer (score 2):

When the user writes and submits a post, save the date they posted on the post's table. Select and count the amount of times they posted today. If they are under their limit, allow the post or else give them the error/warning message.

Answer (score 1):

When a post is made, do something like:

```
// Get last post time and number of posts today from database
$query = "SELECT
            last_post,
            posts_today
          FROM
            users
          WHERE
            id = '$auth->id'";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));

// See if this is the first post today
$isNewDay = date('Y-m-d') != date('Y-m-d',strtotime($result['last_post']));
$postsToday = ($isNewDay) ? 0 : (int) $result['posts_today'];

// Only add post if user is allowed
if ($isNewDay || $postsToday < 3) {
  /*
    Add the post to the database here
  */
  // Update the number of posts today in the database
  $query = "UPDATE
              users
            SET
              last_post = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."',
              posts_today = '".($postsToday + 1)."'
            WHERE
              id = '$auth->id'";
  mysql_query($query);
} else {
  echo "You have already made 3 posts today!";
}
```

...or you could just use a CAPTCHA (as mentioned by others). That's what they're for. Really, you should have one in the signup process...

Comment: I do have a captcha in the sign up and elsewhere, still does not stop manual spamming

Comment: @LightningWrist You need a better CAPTCHA then. Try [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Comment: I use reCaptcha. This is not a captcha issue. It's doing its job. I'm asking how to limit. Totally separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit I know next to nothing on PHP programming, but another option (or addition to the CAPTCHA) would be to use a service such as [StopForumSpam](http://www.stopforumspam.com)

There's an example of [how to use it here](http://sysadminspot.com/programming/generic-php-function-code-to-query-stop-forum-spam-api/) (no idea how good it is, as I don't code PHP (yet)) :)

Comment: (full disclosure: I'm a StopForumSpam moderator) We also have a number of contributions available here: http://www.stopforumspam.com/contributions - plus the official documentation (which are also being rewritten for clarity by the staff presently) for API usage here: http://www.stopforumspam.com/usage